# Reversing Conditions in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the rejected stats from our query and thus for that I have to reverse engineer our queries. For each condition, I have to find out how many records were rejected. I have created below query but still having issues in geeting correct data. Can someone help?

Comment: The question needs more detail about the problem and the desired result

Comment: I have to provide reject stats, these are the conditions in our original sql and I have to provide how many records were rejected for what reason.Like if record is not submitted, it will be rejected and so on.

Comment: To enable members to help you better, please provide as much detail as you can such as table structures with some sample sanitized data, and the structure of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have NULLs, then simply use `NOT`:

```
WHERE NOT (UPPER(SRC.STTS_VOD_C) = 'SUBMITTED_VOD' AND
           CAST(SRC.is_parent_call_vod_c AS INT) = 1 AND
           (CAST(SRC.total_expns_incurred_gzm_c AS INT) > 0 OR
            CAST(SRC.sanofi_total_other_expenses__c AS INT) > 0
           )
          )
```

If the columns can have `NULL`s, then the solution is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes, the columns do have Null and I have to use relational operators in such a manner that I only get count of records rejected for that particular instance.Also, I have to automate this process and i have no idea how to even begin doing this.